# Prevent Cloudflare 524 on long running scripts

Tags: cloudflare

It seems Cloudflare times out after 100 seconds of not receiving a response from the server. I have some scripts that require longer than that to run. Is there anything within Cloudflare that can be used to bypass that limit e.g. page rules? Or is there another way around it without having to recode stuff, setup bypass routes or run on a separate server?